# Reading messages from the server and storing them in file and displaying them in Tkinter

Tags: python

I am reading a file "server.txt" in which I am receiving text messages from clients and displaying them on a Tkinter window. Here the code

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()
root.geometry("500x500")
text_area = Text(frame)
text_area.pack(side=BOTTOM)

while(1):
  text_area.delete(1.0, END)   
  fo = open("server.txt", "r")
  str = fo.read(500000);
  text_area.insert(END,str+'\n')
  print "Read String is : ", str
  # Close opend file
  fo.close()
root.mainloop()
```

It is not working in ubuntu when I open it in command line??

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping through the while function forever before you call root.mainloop(), this means that the Tkinter window will never popup but you will have the print statement in your while statement spammed infintently

Here is the working code, use the after function  [after](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2011-April/083234.html)

```
    from Tkinter import *

# This function will be run every N milliseconds
def get_text(root,val,name):
    # try to open the file and set the value of val to its contents 
    try:
        with open(name,"r") as f:
            val.set(f.read())
    except IOError as e:
        print e
    else:
        # schedule the function to be run again after 1000 milliseconds  
        root.after(1000,lambda:get_text(root,val,name))

root = Tk()
root.minsize(500,500)
eins = StringVar()
data1 = Label(root, textvariable=eins)
data1.config(font=('times', 12))
data1.pack()
get_text(root,eins,"server.txt")
root.mainloop()
```